# Doubts on obstruction theory (Hatcher's book)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration, obstruction-theory

I'm actually studying obstruction theory as presented in the last section of chapter $4$ of the book Algebraic Topology by Allen Hatcher.  He first finds condition so that a space $X$ admits a Postnikov tower of principal fibrations, which is a Postnikov tower

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\vdots & & \vdots\\
@| & @VVV       \\
X @>>> X_3 \\
@| & @VVV       \\
X @>>> X_2\\
@| & @VVV\\
X @>>> X_1
\end{CD}
where any map $ X_n \rightarrow X_{n-1}$ is such that exists a fibration sequence $F\rightarrow E\rightarrow B$ and weak homotopy equivalences $X_n\rightarrow F$ and $X_{n-1}\rightarrow E$ such that

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X_n @>>> X_{n-1} \\
 @VVV & @VVV    \\
F @>>> E@>>> B\\
\end{CD}
commutes.
The problem is that when a few pages later he deals with the problem of finding a map $W\rightarrow X_n$ to complete the commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>>> X_n \\
@VVV & @VVV       \\
W @>>> X_{n-1}\\
\end{CD}
where $(W,A)$ is a $CW$ pair and $A\rightarrow W$ is the inclusion, he supposes that $X_n$ actually is the pullback of the path fibration $PB\rightarrow B$ via $X_{n-1}\rightarrow B$.
Why can he suppose this?

Comment: The pullback you've described is the definition of the homotopy fiber of the map $X_{n-1}\to B$. One may show in general that if $F\to E\to B$ is a fibration sequence, then $F$ is homotopy equivalent to the homotopy fiber of $E\to B$. Now apply this to the fibration sequence $X_n\to X_{n-1}\to B$.

Comment: This was also posted [in math.overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312205/questions-about-obstruction-theory-hatchers-book)